# Can I hide my extension's icon by default?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension doesn't need an icon - it's a one-liner extension that doesn't want to take up space on your extension bar.

How can I hide the icon by default?

Comment: For anyone looking to do this today - note that [Chrome 49 now displays all extension icons](http://uk.pcmag.com/internet-products/75777/news/chrome-49-update-fills-your-toolbar-with-your-exte), even if they don't have a browser action or page action - meaning that @RocketDonkey's answer no longer works :-(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't want an icon, you can omit the `browser_action` parameter from your `manifest.json` (the `default_icon` option is where you usually specify the icon). The `browser_action` section is what controls what you see in the toolbar.

Comment: I kept an empty `browser_action` parameter, and did get a (default) icon. I'll try removing it completely.

Comment: Didn't work for me - even without this parameter, an empty icon is added to the bar.

Comment: @ripper234 Are you running it as an unpacked extension right now? If so, did you verify that the extension reloaded after your changes? I just tried it locally with your manifest and it loads with no icon, so if it is definitely refreshed we can see if there is something in `autologin.js` that is causing the issue (perhaps a call to `chrome.browserAction` or something).

Comment: @ripper234 I just tried the version hosted on github (it was driving me crazy :) ), and it works when you remove the `browser_action` parameter completely. I would suggest trying it again, ensuring that the changes got reflected (which is a constant source of pain for me, since I often don't do that).

Comment: Finally got around to trying this ... and my extension broke! I actually got 69 active users ... please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531372/manifest-file-is-invalid - I'm worried this might affect existing users.

Comment: This seems to have taken care of itself after a few minutes. Odd.

Comment: @ripper234 So all is good now? Happy to keep brainstorming if not.

Comment: All good in this regard, thanks for the help. I'm still having other unrelated issues with another plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531548/how-to-debug-gallery-system-error-please-try-again-later

Comment: @ripper234 And looks like that one got solved - awesome! Good luck with everything.

Comment: this is not the be all answer ... i'm having this issue now. trying to figure out how to make an extension that only runs when one of a site in a list is visited and have it only run a simple background process to alter the look of the site a little. all that is working. but still have a stupid icon, even without `browser_action`

Answer (score 86):

Due to a [change spearheaded by Google](https://blog.google/products/chrome/new-year-new-chrome/), all extensions now must have an icon in the toolbar area or the "overflow" in the menu.

Even if you don't have a `browser_action`, your extension will display an icon (or failing that, a tile with extension name's first letter). If you do not declare a `browser_action`, it will be greyed out and non-interactive, but will still be there.

The idea of this change is to provide visibility of otherwise potentially stealthy extensions ("Hey user, did you even know you have those installed?"). It's, let's put it, *debatable* whether it's the best approach, but that was Google's decision.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would add that it's now up to each user to decide which extension are displayed or not. To do so, right-click on icons you want to hide and select **Hide in Chrome Menu**.

Answer (score 6):

To suppress this behavior, add `"converted_from_user_script": true` to the extension's `manifest.json`. This works as of Chrome 61.

It used to be that visiting a link to a user script (ending in `.user.js`) caused Chrome to package up the user script as a content script extension with a generated manifest which included the `converted_from_user_script` key. Of course, this no longer works because all extensions (except in developer mode) now have to come from the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 5):

Google thought it best to make the icon mandatory and I think so too, for reasons already pointed out by Xan.

Now of course you 're right, when you say that many extensions have no need for an icon, but the requirement of one still gives your extension an identity and Google still gives the user the opportunity to remove it from the toolbar. He simply has to **right click** the extension's icon and then choose **Hide in Chrome menu**.

I know, many users don't really bother to read all of the options under right click, or even right click it at all. But most of them still will make a single left click, to see if there is any option in the fancy new extension they added. You can take advantage of this by making a simple window where you **point out their option of hiding the icon**.