# Manifest file is invalid

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I successfully uploaded a new version of my extension [to the chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/producteev-auto-login/dbmjalgigkhfhmckigghggodkafpfdfl/related) store, and I'm suddenly getting  `Manifest file is invalid` errors when I try to install it.

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/ripper234/producteev-auto-login) (specifically, I tried to upload [this package](https://github.com/ripper234/producteev-auto-login/blob/master/releases/1.4.zip)).

How do I fix it? The one thing I tried to change is make the extensino's icon disappear, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041001/11236). I tried several things like not using a `browser_action` or using a `page_action` instead ... but I keep getting an error when I try to install the extension through the app store (no error on upload though!)

Comment: Closing as too localised because there's not a real problem or answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get this problem when I publish too many times in short succession. I believe your browser is caching the downloaded package (i.e. using a previously downloaded version) but then verifying the package against the new published packaged metadata.

It should correct itself after 10 minutes or so.

This is a very annoying problem for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have taken care of itself after a few minutes. Odd.