# How to debug "Gallery system error, please try again later"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to upload this file: https://github.com/ripper234/explainxkcd/blob/master/releases/0.2.zip to the store, and I keep getting this error:

**Gallery system error, please try again later.**

Meanwhile, updating another extension worked well for me.

I already posted to the [Chromium Apps Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-apps/gsgFZPuSt7s). Anything more I can try in the meantime to debug this?

Comment: It's a common error: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Gallery+system+error%2C+please+try+again+later.%22. Does none of the existing posts help? For instance: Edit manifest.json and bump the version, or remove `key.pem` from your zip file (if applicable).

Comment: @RobW - I bumped the version and have no .pem file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had had the same problem, than I found the solution.

This is all about compressing method.

You should select compressing method as "Store".

I tried on your files, yes It worked, it was uploaded successfully.

Here what I means for Winrar,

[image]

Comment: Success! I didn't use store, but rather moved from jzip to 7zip for creating the archive. Used `deflate` and `Ultimate` and this worked!