# How to create a chrome extension without image on toolbar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, manifest

After reading and understanding how an extension works I tried to create a simple program. Unfortunately, I hit an obstacle because I don't know how to create my extension without image.

I think it is possible because I've seen many extensions without one. So if anyone knows how please help me out. I believe my problem lies in the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "description",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide my extension's icon by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040955/can-i-hide-my-extensions-icon-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer no longer works (because of new behavior in Chrome).  There is no way to not show your icon that's a user's choice now.

See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040955/can-i-hide-my-extensions-icon-by-default)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
```

from your *manifest.json*. You need to pick one **OR none** (none is your case) of:

```
"browser_action": {...},
"page_action": {...},
```