# Place Chrome Extension Icon in Overflow Area

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension and when installed it, Chrome creates an icon next to the omnibar. The icon provides no functionality and I'd like to remove it form such a prominent spot. I know I can't fully hide the icon, but can I set the icon to show in the Icon Overflow area under the hamburger icon by default?

Comment: Any way would be at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction, but there is not.

Comment: Are you asking this from a programmatic point of view (i.e. is there anything that you can do from within your extension to cause this to happen)? Or, are you asking if there is any way for a user to make a selection within Chrome to have the icon not be prominently displayed?

Comment: I'm trying to programmaticly place the icon in the overflow area as suggested by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37521405/2081511).