# Chrome Extension - Open a new tab page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the "iGoogle new tab page" example at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples to test out loading a website from a chrome extension.  However, when I install it in my browser through settings>more tools>extensions>load unpacked extension when I click the icon for the extension it doesn't do anything and the "iGoogle new tab page" option in the menu is grayed out.  Any ideas?

[image: disabled extension]

Comment: you tried to restart chrome ?

Comment: Read the extension's description: it replaces the default new tab page which is shown when the user opens a new tab, the extension and its icon don't do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon is displayed simply because [all extensions must display it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521405/934239). However, it does not have any functionality attached to it, so clicking it does nothing.

---

The first entry in the context menu (with the extension name) normally leads to the URL [specified in the manifest as `homepage_url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/homepage_url).

It is grayed out for locally installed extensions that don't specify a `homepage_url`. For extensions installed from the Store, the default URL is their listing in CWS.

---

As wOxxOm mentions, you may misunderstand the purpose of this sample. It replaces the New Tab page, if your browser is set up to open one.

It's hard to recommend particular documentation for "loading a website from a Chrome extension", but take a look at [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create), it may be what you're seeking.